# jQuery load() and pass to php GET and get data from #div

Tags: php, jquery, object, get, load

I want to send request to PHP file, ie. ?page=1 and get the data from #div from the same php file, and do all using jquery .load();

I'm trying to do this like that:

```
$('#content_text').load("page1.php?page=1" + " #page1_tit");
```

And it doesn't work. I get no data inside #content_text and I have no errors in the console.
Look's like ?page=1 request doesn't work.
Anyone knows how to do that ?

This is the page1.php

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$i = $_GET['page'];

print $i;

include 'db.php';
    if ($db_found) {
    $SQL1 = "SELECT ID, content, tittle FROM pages WHERE ID = '$i'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL1);

    while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    print "<div id=\"#page1_tit\">";
        print $db_field['tittle'];
    print "</div>";
    print "<div id=\"#page1_cont\">";
        print $db_field['content'];
    print "</div>";
    }
    mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
    print $i;
}
?>
```

Comment: The `" + " #div` is a bit much, but it should still work. What's your console say?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very meaningful. What does it do instead of what you want? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Console doesn't get any errors. I was checking page1.php and I'm sure it's working, just javascript doesn't get this code into the #content_text

Comment: Paste the same url into a new tab. See what you get.

Comment: It's working, Diodeus. I was testing it and I'm 100% sure that php file is ok.

Comment: is `page1.php` in the same folder as the file you're calling that script from (excluding any URL rewriting)?

Comment: What do you think you are doing by adding `+"#div"`?

Comment: RainFromHeaven - yes, it's in the same place

Comment: Mike Brant - this +"#div" gets only the content from #div from page1.php.

Comment: Don't you have a typo here? `print $db_field['tittle'];` ("tt")

Comment: please, guys, help me ! I was eaven trying that --> $('#content_tittle_con').load('page1.php?page=1 #page1_tit'); and still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your variable $db_found ist false or your database query returns 0 rows so the while does not run.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="pageloader" name="pageload">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pageloader").click(function(){
$('#content_text').load("page1.php?page=1" + " #page1_tit");
});
});
</script>
```